# Turning the sound off?

Tags: android, super-hexagon

Plain and simple question, I know.

I like playing my mobile games while listening to my own music, and having the game's music over it is quite annoying. But somehow, I see no menu option to mute this app!

I even started looking at apps that would enable me to mute specific apps, like the volume mixer in Windows... No success there either.

Comment: I imagine that there's no option in the game itself to mute it because the gameplay and patterns in the game are pretty linked to the music that plays. Based on that, I'm not sure there would ever be an update to add that option.

Comment: Well it is already implemented in the Windows version, as I can see. There is a nice "options" menu in this version, which I cannot think of any reason for it not to be available on the Android one. Plus according to [this page](http://www.edge-online.com/features/six-super-hexagon-tips-from-one-of-the-best-players-in-the-world/2/) some "pro gamers" of Hexagon actually recommend to turn the sound off. (okay, maybe not to replace it with some other music, but they mention the annoyance of the lady's voiceover)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the mobile version of Super Hexagon doesn't yet have the option to turn off sound. Hopefully, the developers will update the game to include this feature.